Unstable Riccati Matrix ODE
I have the below Riccati ODE:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{\partial A(t)}{\partial t} = A(t)M^{A}A(t) + A(t)U^{A} + (U^{A})^{T}A(t) + R^{A}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Where:
\begin{equation}
A(T) = \begin{pmatrix}
            -K_{S} & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
            0 & -K_{F} & 0 & 0\\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        M^{A} =     \begin{pmatrix}
        20270857.8 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 & \frac{(10^{9})}{3} &  0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & -0.003 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        U^{A} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
            0 & 0.0015 & 8 & -8 \\ 
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    R^{A} = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            -0.588 & -0.588 & 0 & 0  \\
            -0.588 & -0.58875 & -4 & 4\\ 
            0 & -4 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 4 & 0 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Using the value of A at terminal time T, I have been using numerical methods to step backwards in time to try and find solution(s) for discrete timesteps eventually reaching $A(0)$.
However, for any value of $K_{S}$, $K_{F} > 0$ the solution blows up such that the solver fails regardless which method is used. I have been usind scipys solve_ivp function and have tried each of its solvers.
I know that the solution at $A(0)$ should be the same regardless which values of $K_{S}$ and $K_{F}$ as the effect of these terminal conditions should only be apparent approaching T.
Can anyone suggest a way of stabilising this equation for $K_{S}$, $K_{F} > 0$ or suggest an alternative numerical method that I should be using?

Do you mean "Riccati"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Indeed, very sorry for my terrible spelling.

No worries! That equation is regularly misspelled, "Ricatti" or "Ricati", now I can add "Racciti" to the list. :-D (Sorry I can't help at all with the actual question).

The fact that there is a finite-escape time is not necessarily a numerical problem but a property of Riccati equations. Are you sure that this is not the case here?

Indeed, I am fairly certain that this is not the case here as I am trying to replicate the numerical results from a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.15478) where they have resolved this equation with values of K > 0 to produce one of their figures. If the solution had blown up they would not be able to present these results.

@NathanPinel In this case, either you or them have made a mistake in the code. Also, please mention people with @ in your comments so that they can see that you replied to their comment. Otherwise, there will no notification.
